# how to load an inputStream dynamically in HTML5 <audio> tag in java

Tags: java, html, inputstream, audio-streaming, html5-audio

Am receiving a dynamic inputStream from a web service and I want the to insert it in and HTML5 audio tag in order for the user to be able to play it, how can I set the content of the HTML5 tag dynamically (programmatically) ?

Comment: How dynamic input stream constructed?

Comment: if it is perfect stream, you may use like this.    var audio = document.getElementById("audioEl");
audio.src=stream;

Comment: yes it is perfect stream

Comment: Am getting this input stream from a voice mail server

Comment: var audio = document.getElementById("audioEl"); audio.src=stream;

Comment: Shouldn't be like the following : audio.src=stream.toString(); ?

I mean audio.src takes String, not input stream.

Comment: audio element able take streams.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kongaraju/5713587 here is a quick demo. run it locally, this demonstrated adding stream to audio

Answer (score 0):

audio element able to take stream directly

```
<h2>Local-Audio</h2>
        <audio id="audio1" controls="controls" ></audio>
        <button id="btn1" onclick="addStream()">
            Add Stream
        </button>
        <script>
            var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
            var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
            function addStream() {
                getUserMedia({audio : true}, gotStream, function() {});
            }

            function gotStream(stream) {
                audio.src =  window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                audio.play();
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I saw your link and couldn't run your code, where should I insert the URL in order to get the stream lets say that my .mp3 URL

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3

Comment: hello konga ,where should I place my code in order to get the inputStream ?

thats my code that gets the inputStream from the server side:

getvmMsgResp[0].getVmailMessageWAVFile().getDataSource().getInputStream();

Comment: download and save gist locally then run, I thought you are novice to HTML5, replace stream in gotStream callback with inputstream.